# Magento 2.2 custom product attribute not visible on catalog / category page

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes

So I've created 6 custom attributes in my modules using installData.php
let's take two of them:

```
  $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'badge1text',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Badge 1 Text',
                'input' => 'text',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => '',
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => ''
            ]
        );

        /**
         * Insert/Create a seletbox attribute with custom options
         */
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'badge1image',
            [
                'type' => 'int', // data type to be saved in database table
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Badge 1 Background',
                'input' => 'select', // form element type displayed in the form
                'class' => '',
                'source' => 'UNBXD\ProductAttributes\Model\Config\Source\MyCustomOptions',
                'global' =>\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_STORE, ,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => true,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => ''
            ]
        );
```

and here's my custom select source:

```
class MyCustomOptions extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{
    /**
     * Get all options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if ($this->_options === null) {
            $this->_options = [
                ['value' => '',  'label' => __('Please Select Background Color')],
                ['value' => '1', 'label' => __('Purple')],
                ['value' => '2', 'label' => __('Blue')],
                ['value' => '3', 'label' => __('Pink')],
                ['value' => '4', 'label' => __('Green')]
            ];
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }

    /**
     * Get text of the option value
     * 
     * @param string|integer $value
     * @return string|bool
     */
    public function getOptionValue($value) 
    { 
        foreach ($this->getAllOptions() as $option) {
            if ($option['value'] == $value) {
                return $option['label'];
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem is that 'Badge 1 Background' value isn't visible on catalog / category page. Only 1st value placeholder is accessible '**Please Select Background** ' ...not real value. **On product page all is fine**.
I've try to used those code to display value on catalog:

```
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('badge1image'); 
$attr_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); 
echo $attr_value;
```

What I've missed on InstallData file? Looks like text field is visible but not select with dropdown options...

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get product attributr (SELECT) value from $_productCollection even if it's not available from foreach loop.

```
 $productName = $_product->getName();
   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_product->getId());
   $my_value = $product->getData('my_attribute');
```

Problem SOLVED!